# straight SATA cable vs angled SATA cable

Tags: ssd, sata, cable

**Is that possible straight SATA cable is for ASATA3 slots and angled SATA cable is for SATA3 slots?** I've ever bend a straight SATA cable into almost 90 degree and found it not working , but I pretty sure it is not gonna break it just because i tried to bend it

Story Intro:

2 SATA cables comes with box of B450 AORUS M

1. Initially, I connect (2.5" SSD) into ASATA3 slot and run the PC fine for few days (with straight cable)
2. Few days later, I install M.2 (PCIe) and PC no longer detect (2.5" SSD) unbootable
3. Confused and upset me, tried (angled SATA cable) not work as well (thought might pressing SSD too hard while fitting it on case) **but the actual reason here is ASATA3 slot conflict lane with M.2 lanes, meaning, I have total of 6 SATA slots on motherboard, however, once M.2 SSD is installed, 2 or 3 SATA slots (aka. ASATA3) will completely down and undetectable until M.2 is removed.**
4. Connect (2.5 SSD) to SATA slots, and it works well again (with angled cable)
5. Shut down PC and reuse the straight cable (try bending it while repluging it) , unbootable again.

So the point is

**straight SATA cable might for ASATA3 slots only**

or

**my straight cable has broken (but no point for that because cable was always made bending here and there while in box**

If I really want to prove it I have to remove the M.2 and reconnect to ASATA slot with straight cable (remove M.2 means remove GPU as well in order to do that), so better anyone just answer my first line of question would be good :)

Answer (score 4):

SATA connections are highly susceptible to being put under any pressure at all; they can cause all sorts of weird issues, from bad I/O to the drive not being recognised at all.

Get a can of contact cleaner, douse plugs & sockets liberally [with the power completely off & allow good time to dry], then try again - using whichever cable puts least or no pressure on the connection. If you have to bend a cable, make the bend as far away from the actual plug as possible - use longer cables if necessary. Bends close to the plug will put far greater strain on the connection.

The cables are probably OK, but the connections are extremely sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between straight and angled SATA cables. (If with angled you mean having 90 degree angled connector at one or both ends).

But bending a SATA cable in a too tight bend (e.g. wrapping it around your finger) may damage it. Even though it may still make electrical contact and has no visible damage it is possible it doesn't support high-speed (== high frequency) data-transmission anymore. (Or give lots of errors.)

The higher the SATA version, the higher the frequencies and the more change that the cable isn't good enough. Unbending it doesn't remove the damage. The internal core of the wires deforms and stays deformed.

In general, as long as the radius of the bend isn't tighter than approx. 1 inch (2.5 cm) there should be no problem.

The SATA connectors themselves can be a bit subject to connection problems. Make sure the plugs are properly seated and there is no dust in the connectors before you plug them in.
(And don't pull them out of a socket by yanking on the cable. Grip the plug and if it has a locking tab press that to release the plug from the socket.)

PS: Old SATA1 cables could also not be rated for SATA2 or SATA3 speeds, but most cables not older than 10 years will be OK for SATA2 and 3.

Comment: There are actually 2 different angled sata cables, 90 and 270 depending on which direction you want the cable to point in relation to the drive, found that out the hard way on a Dell, a regular 90 would not work in the D5150 or E510 case.

Comment: @Moab - They are also sometimes called "right angled" and "left angled' connectors.